# How to get mnemonic seed from Trezor

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, trezor, hardware-wallet

I created an **encrypted** wallet with trezor chrome app. Then I ran

> ./simplewallet -hardware-wallet 0

and a new wallet was created on the trezor but no mnemonic seed was displayed. How do I get the seed for this wallet?

I noticed that trezor uses the previous version of Monero. Might the problem be that? Is the problem that the wallet is encrypted? When the wallet is not encrypted the seed is displayed.